# Get URI from Bitmap?

Tags: android, image, listview, error-handling, uri

**What I try to do**

---

I got a ListView which I've filled over my SimpleListAdapter, the data comes from a JSON-File. Now I wrote a ImageDownloader and I'd like to but the Image into the ListView. But I allways get this Error here: `resolve Uri failed on bad bitmap uri.`

**Question**

---

What do I need to change to get the Code working. Thx for your help in advance!
You find the code down here!

**Code**

---

ChannelActivity.class

```
package de.stepforward;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import de.stepforward.web.ShowVideo;


import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;



public class ChannelActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    String result = "";
    String line = null;
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    //get the Data from URL
    try{
    URL url = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/users/TheStepForward/uploads?alt=json&format=1"); 

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    //read d response till d end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    result = sb.toString();
    Log.v("log_tag", "Append String " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try{
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject feed = json.getJSONObject("feed");
        JSONArray entrylist = feed.getJSONArray("entry");

        for(int i=0;i<entrylist.length();i++){
            //Get Title
            JSONObject movie = entrylist.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject title = movie.getJSONObject("title");
            String txtTitle = title.getString("$t");
            Log.d("Title", txtTitle);

            //Get Description
            JSONObject content = movie.getJSONObject("content");
            String txtContent = content.getString("$t");
            Log.d("Content", txtContent);

            //Get Link
            JSONArray linklist = movie.getJSONArray("link");
            JSONObject link = linklist.getJSONObject(0);
            String txtLink = link.getString("href");
            Log.d("Link", txtLink);


            //Get Thumbnail
            JSONObject medialist = movie.getJSONObject("media$group");
            JSONArray thumblist = medialist.getJSONArray("media$thumbnail");
            JSONObject thumb = thumblist.getJSONObject(2);
            String txtThumb = thumb.getString("url");
            Log.d("Thumb", txtThumb.toString());

            //ImageLoader
            Bitmap bitmap = getImageBitmap(txtThumb);

            String picture = bitmap.toString();

            //String Array daraus machen und in Hashmap füllen
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Thumb", picture);
            map.put("Title", txtTitle);
            map.put("Content", txtContent);
            map.put("Link", txtLink);
            mylist.add(map);

        }
        //ListView füllen
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.lit, 
                new String[] { "Thumb","Title","Content","Link"}, 
                new int[] { R.id.img_video,R.id.txt_title,R.id.txt_subtitle});      
        setListAdapter(adapter);


        //OnClickLister um Youtube-Video zu öffnen
        final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                    //Video-Link auslesen
                    Map<String, String> map = mylist.get(position);
                    String link = map.get("Link");
                    Log.d("Link", link);

                    //Link übergeben, Activity starter
                    final Intent Showvideo = new Intent(ChannelActivity.this, ShowVideo.class);
                    Showvideo.putExtra("VideoLink", link);
                    startActivity(Showvideo);


                }
            });



    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
    }
    private Bitmap getImageBitmap(String url) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SHIT", "Error getting bitmap", e);
        }
        return bm;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably trying to decode a .jpg or .png as a bitmap.

Have a look at this question & answer.

[resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri” when putting image on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095676/resolveuri-failed-on-bad-bitmap-uri-when-putting-image-on-listview)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) only works with TextViews and it looks like you are trying to use it to work with an ImageView.

You'll need to create a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and in the [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method, manually set the data in the views.

Comment: isn't it possible when i overgive the path from the picture that it gets shown?

Comment: it works over the SimpleAdapter, if you like to have the code I can hand it out to you :D