# Android resolveuri failed on bad bitmap uri

Tags: android, image, bitmap, upload, uri

I'm new to android, trying to uplaod an image from gallery. Seems like the path I get is fine, but I'm not sure about using it right to upload an image.

logcat says: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: [/storage/sdcard0/VK/FjKgT9DodNM.jpg, 2130837564, 2130837563, 2130837565, 2130837566].

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

booksCovers here is an ArrayList of Objects with pictures.

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.change_picture:
        onChangePictureClick();
        break;
    case R.id.delete_element:
        /*
        ...
        */
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
};

private void onChangePictureClick()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), CHANGE_PICTURE);
}

    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_view_contex_menu, menu);
    info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;// contains information about object of which ContextMenu was called from
};

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch (requestCode) 
        {
        case INPUT_ACTIVITY:
            /*
            ...
            */
            break;
        case CHANGE_PICTURE:
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, 
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            booksCovers.set(info.position, picturePath);
            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = booksArray.get(info.position);
            hashMap.remove(coverkey);
            hashMap.put(coverkey, booksCovers);
            booksArray.set(info.position, hashMap);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095676/resolveuri-failed-on-bad-bitmap-uri-when-putting-image-on-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now. Just changed this:

```
hashMap.put(coverkey, booksCovers.get(info.position));
```